# CRM 2011 Chart - How to Show All Values in Legend?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, asp.net-charts, fetchxml

Using the default CRM 2011 Opportunities by Sales Stage Funnel Chart, how can you get it to show all of the stages in the legend even if there isn't data for each stage? This seems like a simple problem but I'm stumped.

The Chart only presents data retrieved by the Fetch and the Fetch won't necessarily have at least one record for each stage. Additionally the Funnel chart cannot have more than one series.

This is what I came up with but it does not work as a Funnel chart. Swapping to a radar chart at least does something by the layout is worthless for this type of data.

```
<visualization>
  <visualizationid>{BA88CAC2-637F-E011-8E24-00155D840900}</visualizationid>
  <name>Opportunities by Sales Stage</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>opportunity</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
            <entity name="opportunity">
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_1" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count" />
                <attribute groupby="true" alias="groupby_column" name="salesstagecode">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_2" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="200000" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_3" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="200001" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_4" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count" >
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="200002" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_5" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="100000000" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_6" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="100000001" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_7" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count" >
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="100000002" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
                <attribute alias="aggregate_column_8" name="opportunityid" aggregate="count">
                    <filter type="or">
                        <condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="100000003" />
                    </filter>
                </attribute>
            </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category>
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="aggregate_column_1" />
          </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_2" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_3" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_4" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_5" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_6" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_7" />
            </measurecollection>
            <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="aggregate_column_8" />
            </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="55,118,193; 197,56,52; 149,189,66; 117,82,160; 49,171,204; 255,136,35; 97,142,206; 209,98,96; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83">
      <Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,1" Color="55,118,193" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,200000" Color="197,56,52" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,200001" Color="149,189,66" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,200002" Color="117,82,160" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,100000000" Color="49,171,204" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,100000001" Color="255,136,35" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,100000002" Color="97,142,206" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
          <Series ChartType="Funnel" Name="o:salesstagecode,100000003" Color="209,98,96" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="FunnelLabelStyle=Outside, FunnelNeckHeight=0, FunnelPointGap=1, FunnelNeckWidth=5 ">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
          </Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea>
          <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Legends>
        <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Legends>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
      </Titles>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work because, as you mention, the Funnel chart unfortunately doesn't allow multiple series.
If it did, you would also need to add  tags around each attribute and filter in order for the filter to work.

I'm assuming your funnel chart shows the sum for each stage, so you could add a dummy record for each of them and make sure those are included in your View. On the dummy record the values are 0, so they won't contribute to the sum. You just need to be a little creative with your Advanced Find when incl. them.

You can see a more advanced approach to adding dummy records here http://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/include-records-with-no-value-in-charts/

The approach you were taking with your xml would work if you had a stacked column chart instead, although you would need to add the above mentioned  tags. You can see an example of that here http://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/aggregate-total-on-top-of-stacked-column-charts-or-bar-charts-in-ms-crm-2011/